# Undocumented --read-environment in ifup/ifdown/ifquery

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I read Debian's systemd network startup units and found that
each of `ifup/ifdown/ifquery` is run with `--read-environment`, but
I cannot find this option in `man`. Could any one point to a description of this thing?

K.

Answer (score 2):

These are Debian's tweaks to let SysV init script settings from  /etc/default/networking apply to systemd service file.

Namely:

- CONFIGURE_INTERFACES which disables interfaces configuration on boot
  if set to "no".
- EXCLUDE_INTERFACES, a list of interfaces to exclude from
  configuration on boot (shell wildcards available).
- VERBOSE set to 'yes' for extra messages.

They are undocumented as internals to the integration of ifupdown into systemd.

source:
[Read /etc/default/networking when started from systemd. Closes: #806883](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/commit/c29820f370a4905b836660ee4cf0162cdafdac66)

> Add an undocumented --read-environment option which will cause the
>   VERBOSE, CONFIGURE_INTERFACES and EXCLUDE_INTERFACES environment
>   variables to be read and act in the same way as with ifupdown's SysV
>   init script. This allows the use of
>   EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/networking in the systemd service file.